# how to develop a Lambda based S3 file management application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am planning to develop a web application which can perform some basic text edit functions (like insert and delete) on S3 files. Could anyone show me a path forward? I am currently learning Lambda, and have followed tutorial here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

I can create a Lambda function which can modify files on S3, and call the function by AWS CLI now. What else do I need to know and do to create this web application? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to look at [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/). This can be the front end to your web application.

Also note that S3 is a block storage mechanism, and if your file edits are too frequent it is not suitable for your use case because every time you want to edit the text you will have to download the entire file, modify that and upload that back again. And be mindful of the [S3 eventual consistency](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#CoreConcepts)

> **Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model**
>
> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. The caveat is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides eventual consistency for read-after-write.